# How to block specific username from ssh?

Tags: security, sshd

I have `testuser` and I want that user to be able log-in locally, but not via `ssh`. How can I implement that?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Put `DenyUsers user1 user2 user3` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Answer (score 16):

Artyom answer is correct. 
I'd just like to point that there is also the possibility to opt for a 'white-list' approach instead of the 'black-list' one by putting a line like this in /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

`AllowUsers AuthorizedUser1 AuthorizedUser2`

and reloading ssh service (`service ssh restart`)

Then every other user will be denied ssh access (be careful not to lock yourself out ;-) )

Comment: you can also make access tighter even more by `AllowUser AuthorizedUser1@[ip-address]` I believe. This should only allow that specific user when coming from the mentioned IP address