# How to exclude someone when PubkeyAuthentication no in sshd_config

Tags: sshd

I want to set `PubkeyAuthentication no` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, but someone should be excluded, i.e: John

Comment: who can give me a help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to block specific username from ssh?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/853252/how-to-block-specific-username-from-ssh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add something like this to your `sshd_config`:

```
Match User John
    PubkeyAuthentication yes
```

Don't forget to `sudo systemctl reload sshd`

Comment: [root@login03 ~]# systemctl restart sshd   and 

[root@login03 ~]# sudo systemctl reload sshd

Comment: I got error message : Job for sshd.service invalid.

Comment: my configuration content is:PubkeyAuthentication no                                                  
    Match User John                                                                                                                          
            PubkeyAuthentication yes

Comment: Add something at the bottom of sshd_config, and it works OK!!